# Vb.net - Regex to create url

Tags: vb.net

I am attempting to generate clean URLs from the `titles` I am receiving back from an API. I've created a function with regex to do this. My current function works for majority, but I am having issues with one title and having the return value have an extra `-` at the end of it which is creating issues with my URLs. For example, in my title `"Hospital Services in Washington"` with the current regex function my return would be `hospital-services-` when I am expecting to return without the `-` at the end and return `hospital-services`. I am currently stuck on what changes needs to be made in order to have my desired results. Majority of the other titles are returning just fine but with an expection of the example above.

Examples of working titles: `Cedars Sinai Medical Center` which converts to `cedar-sinai-medical-center`

My problem seems to occur when attempting to remove the `in Washington` from the text or any state name from the title it leaves behind an `-`

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
Private Function GenerateReportsFriendlyURL(ByVal url As String)
    Dim cleanURL As String = Regex.Replace(url, "^A-Za-z0-9\-/s]", "")
    cleanURL = cleanURL.Replace(",", "")
    cleanURL = cleanURL.Replace("'", "")
    cleanURL = cleanURL.Replace(" and ", " ")
    cleanURL = cleanURL.Replace("’", "%E2%80%99")
    cleanURL = RetrieveNameOnly(cleanURL)

    Dim builder As New StringBuilder(cleanURL.Replace(" &", ""))

    Return builder.Replace(" ", "-").ToString().Insert(builder.Length - 0, "").ToLower()
End Function
```

Comment: Your regex looks broken. Can you please check and give examples of text that works and text that fails?

Comment: I provided some more detail in the question of occurrences that work and when the text fails

Comment: What's the RetrieveNameOnly(cleanURL) method?  Does that strip out the "in Washington" Part?  Is it possible that you have a space at the end of your string? Does Dim builder As New StringBuilder(cleanURL.Replace(" &", "").Trim()) help?

Comment: Agree with Enigmativity, looks like that regex is missing a `[` at the start

Answer (score 0):

I've no idea what you're trying to accomplish with the "turning the builder into a string then create a new string by inserting a zero length string after the end of the string" part of this:

```
Dim builder As New StringBuilder(cleanURL.Replace(" &", ""))
Return builder.Replace(" ", "-").ToString().Insert(builder.Length - 0, "").ToLower()
```

But from the problem you say, that your field contains trailing `-`, you should probably be doing:

```
cleanURL = RetrieveNameOnly(cleanURL)

Return cleanURL.Replace(" &", "").Trim().ToLower().Replace(" ", "-")
```